# Use DSL wifi router as access-point?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

Have existing U-verse router with e-net ports and "b/g" wifi.

Have an old SR350N dsl wifi "n" router. Can I add this to my LAN to be used simply as a wireless "n" access point? (Router has one RJ11 "dsl" port and four 10/100 e-net ports, no e-net WAN port.)

Thanks.

Comment: No- I tried doing this a long time ago too by buying the cheapest router I could find on Ebay. Even if this was possible, your connection would be really slow since the router is designed for DSL.

Comment: @kirill2485 The access point portion of the router is typically implemented almost entirely in hardware. So long as you stick to the encryption mechanisms it performs in hardware, the relatively slow CPU shouldn't matter. Compared to his existing b/g WiFi router, this will probably be at least somewhat better.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Make sure to disable the router's DHCP server.

Assign it a LAN IP address inside the range the other router handles but, ideally, outside its DHCP range. For example, if the other router's LAN address is 192.168.0.1 and its DHCP range is 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.200, 192.168.0.2 would be a good LAN address for the other router.

Connect a LAN port on one router to a LAN port on the other router.

You wouldn't want an Ethernet WAN port anyway -- the router isn't connected to a WAN.

Comment: Sometimes (I saw in some dlink DSL routers) there is an option called "multi AP isolation". uncheck that option.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted several of the wireless settings including channel selection (not "automatic") and others. I tried turning down the signal strength of the U-verse 2wire 3800 router to 20 percent (the lowest setting) and confirming that the SR350N's signal strength was 100 percent. Standing close to the SR350N (and about 50 ft and 3 rooms away from the 3800 I still could not get an IP address.

Only when I turned off the 3800's wireless would the SR350N give me an IP. Repeatedly. And the speed was quite decent. Worked quite normally.

So my conclusion: the radio circuits of the SR350N are quite poor and don't play nice in the company of any other wireless signals.